# Does the iPhone support any DXT compression algorithms?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, compression

I see it has PVR decompress routines, but I have some DXT1-5 compressed images I would like to display instead.  I guess I could manually decompress or work out a way to change the format of the source images offline, but i'd be nice to have some sort of support natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no native support for DXT compression. Use PVRTC, which the GPU can decompress in hardware, or don't compress your textures in the first place (decompressing DXT on the fly gives you a performance hit and visual quality degradation without the benefit in memory usage!)

Comment: But it gives a huge benefit in 2D games storage size!

Comment: Alexander: so use PVRTC, which is comparable in terms of compression/quality tradeoff and is actually supported.